# MouseUp not firing if the MouseMove after mouse down

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, .net-core-3.0

Basically what the title say, I have a ScrollViewer with an Image inside.
I'm subscribing from the Image to MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp, MouseMove.

My problem arise when I left click and while holding the button down, move the cursor and then release (Selection Tool) the MouseLeftButtonUp event is not fired. But If I left click and don't move the cursor and release the button. It's fired.

My guess is that since I moved the mouse, wpf decide that I don't care anymore if the button is released? There is any workaround for this? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you please post the code you have. A description will not help us find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I fix it, the problem was that I was drawing an adorn. That adorn was getting in the way of the Hit Test. So I wasn't getting the MouseLeftButtonUp. The weird thing is that I wasn't subscribing to that method in the Adorn. So why the adorn mark the event as handled?
Anyway the problem is fixed.

Comment: I've the same iusse. can you add more details, please? @InusualZ

Comment: Ohh man, this was so long ago. But if I remember correctly you have to make the adorn ignore mouse hit events.